# Как дать рамку картинкой css?

Tags: html, css

Собственно есть рамка в фотошопе, но как сверстать - не знаю. Получается криво.. Делал через border-image

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используй border-image

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант, на основе [jsfiddle #1](http://jsfiddle.net/e9eUU/), [jsfiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/x3sme/)
`display: inline-block` для срабатывания верхнего `margin` без этого он схлопывается и эффекта бордера не будет.

```css
.outside {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-size: 14px 14px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, black, black 5px, transparent 5px, transparent 10px);
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.inside {
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <div class="inside"></div>
</div>
```

[Поддержка repeating-linear-gradient](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-repeating-gradients)